# I am trying to update a Quadtree code to an Octree

Tags: c#, rhino, grasshopper

I am trying to Use the QuadTree code to develop an Octree code. However I am stuck when it comes to changing the Rectangle3d to a Box. Basically I have a function to split the nodes, when slitting the rectangle I used the width and height and divided them, then use the constructor - Rectangle3d(Plane, Double, Double) but I am stuck as to which constructor to use and how to calculate it when I change from Rectangle3d to Box. Can anyone help me with this?

```
  public static Octree oct;
  public static DataTree < Point3d > psOUT;
  public static List<Line> lns = new List<Line>();



 //////////Octree////////

  public class Octree
{

public int MAX_OBJECTS = 10;
public int MAX_LEVELS = 8;

private int level;
private List<Point3d>objects;
private Box bounds;
private Octree[] nodes;

/*
* Constructor
*/
public Octree(int pLevel, Box pBounds)
{
  level = pLevel;
  objects = new List<Point3d>();
  bounds = pBounds;
  nodes = new Octree[8];

}

// implement the five methods of a Octree: clear, split, getIndex, insert, and retrieve.

/*
* Clears the Octree
*/
public void clear()
{
  objects.Clear();

  for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Length; i++)
  {
    if (nodes[i] != null)
    {
      nodes[i].clear();
      nodes[i] = null;
    }
  }
}



/*
 * Splits the node into 8 subnodes
 */
private void split()
{
  double subWidth = bounds.X * 0.5;
  double subDepth = bounds.Y * 0.5;
  double subHeight = bounds.Z *0.5;
  double x = bounds.X.T0;
  double y = bounds.Y.T0;
  double z = bounds.Z.T0;


  nodes[3] = new Quadtree(level + 1, new Box(Plane.WorldXY, new Point3d(x + subWidth, y, 0), new Point3d(x + 2 * subWidth, y + subHeight, 0)));
  nodes[2] = new Quadtree(level + 1, new Box(Plane.WorldXY, new Point3d(x, y, 0), new Point3d(x + subWidth, y + subHeight, 0)));
  nodes[1] = new Quadtree(level + 1, new Box(Plane.WorldXY, new Point3d(x, y + subHeight, 0), new Point3d(x + subWidth, y + 2 * subHeight, 0)));
  nodes[0] = new Quadtree(level + 1, new Box(Plane.WorldXY, new Point3d(x + subWidth, y + subHeight, 0), new Point3d(x + 2 * subWidth, y + 2 * subHeight, 0)));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late but here it goes:

Considering you have a Box in 3D space already constructed. In order to divide it into 8 smaller boxes you can use the X,Y,Z coordinate interval between each of the corners and the box center point. So, you would have something like this:

```
private List<Box> Split(Box box)
{
    List<Box> boxes = new List<Box>();
    foreach(Point3d corner in box.GetCorners())
    {
        Box newbox = CreateBoxFromPlaneAndTwoCorners(box.Plane, box.Center, corner);
        boxes.Add(newbox);
    }
    return boxes;
}

private Box CreateBoxFromPlaneAndTwoCorners(Plane plane, Point3d cornerA, Point3d cornerB) {
    plane.RemapToPlaneSpace(cornerA, out Point3d remapA);
    plane.RemapToPlaneSpace(cornerB, out Point3d remapB);
    Interval intX = new Interval(remapA.X,remapB.X);
    Interval intY = new Interval(remapA.Y,remapB.Y);
    Interval intZ = new Interval(remapA.Z,remapB.Z);

    return new Box(plane,intX,intY,intZ);
}
```